# Message in the backend of typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I've tried to add some message in typo3 backend, but without success.
I know for Flash messages but I just can't make it work.

[image]

How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you really need a flash message, or is it just some kind of information you want to display? In this case, you could use system messages - they are shown at the login screen.

Comment: Actually, I need just to display some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in one of my extensions and here is the snippet:

```
$messageQueue = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
    FlashMessageQueue::class,
    'core.template.flashMessages'
);
$messageQueue->addMessage(
    new FlashMessage(
        'text',
        'title',
        FlashMessage::OK,
        true
    )
);
```

Most important is the attribute `'core.template.flashMessages'` when instantiiating the `FlashMessageQueue`.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this and how to use it.
If you can give me some further details.

Comment: You need an extension which hooks into the backend template service. I thought you have that yet.